# Problem plotting in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I have to draw a random curve in TikZ, connecting the origin to infinity. I thought the easiest way to do that would be to plot `sin(x)-x` from the origin to the left. This way it connects 0 to infinity and seems random enough because of its oscillations. I looked at the documentation, and it seems the right way to do this should be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (-6,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[-latex] (0,-6) -- (0,6);
\draw[color=blue,domain=-6:0,smooth,variable=\x] plot (\x,sin(\x r)-\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Axes, then curve, and that's all. Except it isn't the right way, because the result is:

```
./TikZ_plot.tex:9: Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 ...,smooth,variable=\x] plot (\x,sin(\x r)-\x)
```

So what do I do? How do I draw this plot, and what am I doing wrong? After all, the doc has:

```
\tikz \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3.141:3.141,smooth,variable=\t] plot ({\t*sin(\t r)},{\t*cos(\t r)});
```

which, save for lacking the `tikzpicture` wrapper and the axes, and having that `\tikz` command, is perfectly identical to my code, save for the variable name. So what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add curly brackets around the coordinates with other brackets so that Tikz doesn't misinterpret them.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (-6,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[-latex] (0,-6) -- (0,6);
\draw[color=blue,domain=-6:0,smooth,variable=\x] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)-\x});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The curly braces are only needed for `sin(\x r)-\x` because of the parentheses. Otherwise the closing parentheses is misinterpreted as end of the coordinate.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek True, but always seen it being used for the single coordinate, I thought it was necessary. :D I'll fix it.

Comment: _Full derp moment_ Oh yes. I'd missed those braces… :)